# Name of the maximum value per column value assigned to a new column

Tags: excel, max

Hello I have the excel sheet below and would like to have a column that displays the name of maximum value as many times as the ID exists in the dataset for each ID

initial sheet

| ID | Value | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | x |
| A | 2 | y |
| A | 3 | z |
| B | 5 | k |
| B | 6 | l |
| B | 7 | w |

The desired output is:

| ID | Value | name | name with max value per ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | x | z |
| A | 2 | y | z |
| A | 3 | z | z |
| B | 5 | k | w |
| B | 6 | l | w |
| B | 7 | w | w |

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service, so please show us what you have tried and where you have run into problems. Also the version of Excel might be useful if a formula solution seems optimal. (Other possible solutions might use VBA or Power Query).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID is column A, B, etc. In column D you'll want the following formula:

`=INDEX( [table], MATCH(1, (MAXIFS([Value Column],[ID column],A2)=[Value Column]) *([ID Column] = A2),0),3)`

Then hit `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` to turn it into an array formula and drag it down. Each instance I have [ ] I'm naming the data for the column from the header to the bottom for each. Substitute you cell or named references in their place. It's important that each of these are locked references and the same height (if column A goes down 8 rows, column b must as well)

Note: MAXIFS is only available in Excel 2019 and Office 365

Comment: May want to note that MAXIFS is only available in Excel 2019 and Office 365.

Comment: As an alternative you can use the `MAXIF`. I personally, the plural since it's more scalable with other criteria.

Comment: There is no MAXIF.  They went straight to MAXIFS and cut out the singular

Answer (score 0):

If one has Office 365 with FILTER():

```
=@FILTER(C:C,(A:A=A2)*(B:B=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For older excel version you can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE` array formula:

```
=INDEX(C:C,N(IF(1,MATCH(A2&AGGREGATE(14,6,(B:B*(A:A=A2)),1),A:A&B:B,0))))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Office365 you can make everything array/ranges. I also assumed and your table starts in column A

```
=INDEX(C2:C7,MATCH(MAXIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,A2:A7),B2:B7,0))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it does not take into consideration the ID on the match.  so if B4 was also `7` it would return `z` for all 6 rows.